# Proof that a certain derivation is well defined

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have spent several hours on this, apparently straightforward issue. This is with reference to page 17 in the following notes

http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/615.pdf

Suppose, $R$ is a commutative ring, $W$ a multiplicatively closed subset in $R$, $M$ an $R$-module. If $D:R\to M$ is a derivation, then $W^{-1}D: W^{-1}R\to W^{-1}M$ is a derivation where $W^{-1}D$ acts on $\frac{r}{w}$ by the quotient rule, i.e. maps $\frac{r}{w}$ to $\frac{wD(r)-rD(w)}{w^2}$.

I have tried several manipulations, but I am unable to show that this map is well defined. I would appreciate if anyone can help me see what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that it suffices to check $(W^{-1}D)\frac{r}{w}=(W^{-1}D)\frac{xr}{xw}$ for $w,x$ in $W$, $r$ in $R$, and that this is straightforward.

Comment: More precisely, let $W^{-1}D$ act on $W\times R$ by the quotient rule, and check $(W^{-1}D)(xr,xw)\sim(W^{-1}D)(r,w)$.

Comment: @Pierre Yes, that's essentially what's behind my answer - which I had hope to elaborate but hadn't had the time.

Comment: Same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052153/extension-of-r-linear-derivation-to-localization , where Hanno gave a beautiful answer.

Answer (score 4):

First observe that if some $s$ kills $r$, i.e. $sr=0$, then $s^2$ kills $Dr$.  Indeed, $$s^2Dr=s(sDr)=s(D(sr)-rDs)=-srDs=0.$$

Now lets assume $r/w=r'/w'$, and that $s\in W$ kills $rw'-r'w$.  I claim that $s^2$ kills $$w'^2(rDw-wDr)-w^2(r'Dw'-w'Dr').$$
We have some calculation:$$w'^2(rDw-wDr)-w^2(r'Dw'-w'Dr')$$
$$=w'^2rDw-w'^2wDr-w^2r'Dw'+w^2w'Dr'$$
$$=w'rD(ww')-ww'D(rw')-wr'D(ww')+ww'D(wr')$$
$$=(rw'-r'w)D(ww')-ww'D(rw'-r'w).$$
Since $s^2$ kills both $rw'-r'w$ and $D(rw'-r'w)$, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

$\rm\displaystyle\ \frac{r}w \equiv 0\:\ \Rightarrow\:\ s\:r = 0\ \Rightarrow\ s^2 \bigg(\!\!\!\frac{r}w\!\!\bigg)' =\ \frac{s\ ((s\:r)'-s'r)}{w}\: -\:\frac{s^2\:r\:w'}{w^2} =\: 0\:\ \Rightarrow\:\ \bigg(\!\!\!\frac{r}w\!\!\bigg)'\!\equiv\: 0$

**Note** $\ $ This proof essentially inlines the lemma that $\rm\:(sr/(sw))' = (r/w)'.$ You may find it more conceptual to proceed indirectly using that lemma (which is how I found the above direct proof).

Comment: @Matt  I added a note to clarify the essence of the matter.

Comment: My joke wasn't that good anyways.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is not a complete proof. The goal is not to prove that any representative of $0$ gets sent to $0$, but to prove that two representatives of the same fraction get sent to the same value. I do not see how the former implies the latter, as we are lacking linearity of whatever form.

Answer (score 1):

[New version. I hadn't noticed the fact that the derivation was module-valued. Sorry. (July 31, 2011, GMT)]

Let $D:R\to M$ be a derivation and $W\subset R$ a multiplicative system. Claim: there is a unique derivation $W^{-1}D:W^{-1}R\to W^{-1}M$ satisfying 
$$(W^{-1}D)\left(\frac{a}{s}\right)=\frac{sD(a)-aD(s)}{s^2}$$ for all $a$ in $R$ and $s$ in $W$.

The uniqueness is clear. Let's prove the existence.

Recall that the relation $\sim$ defined on $R\times W$ by $(a,s)\sim(b,t)$ iff $atu=bsu$ for some $u$ in $W$ is an equivalence relation, and that $W^{-1}R$ is defined as the quotient.

Define the relation $\heartsuit$ on $R\times W$ by $(a,s)\heartsuit(b,t)$ iff $b=au$ and $t=su$ for some $u$ in $W$. Then $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $\heartsuit$.

Define $d:R\times W\to W^{-1}M$ by 
$$d(a,s)=\frac{sD(a)-aD(s)}{s^2}\quad.$$ One checks that $(a,s)\heartsuit(b,t)$ implies $(W^{-1}D)(a,s)=(W^{-1}D)(b,t)$. Thus $d$ induces a map $W^{-1}D:W^{-1}R\to W^{-1}M$, which is easily seen to be a derivation.

Comment: Is this following from tensoring $W^{-1}D$ to induce the derivation? I mean considering the map $1_{W^{-1}D}\otimes D$. However, I do not get the desired map as described above by tensoring operation. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @user45765 - Note that $D$ is **not** $R$-linear.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.